# Will Using GitHub Offline in External Harddrive Detect Changes?

Tags: git, github

So I made a web repository in my hard drive for offline use.
No online pushing. No online repositories. Just offline.

I usually use my web on my PC at home and carry it over work in hard drive and using office PC to do it again.

**Will changes I made in office PC be detected when I'm using it again in my home PC?**

Answer (score 0):

> No online pushing. No online repositories. Just offline.

If you don't have the code on git server it will not be visible to others as you mentioned.

> Will changes I made in office PC be detected when I'm using it again in my home PC?
>   Only if you copy the `.git` folder as well. This is where git stores the information.

Every time you execute `git add` git start to track changes and store them inside the `.git` folder, as well for commits data.

So if you copy this file or simply carrying the HD with you, you will see those changes, if you only copy the content of the folder you will not see them

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using any CLI. My case is Github GUI Offline. I'm using it to monitor changes. Is it the same?